# bootstrap-switch check box value always "on"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing CMS and on Add Form I'm using [Bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html) in my form. But It always return `checked` or `on` value.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hassaan_developer/bh64jfsz/)

CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){

    var s = $('#status').val();
    $("#status").change(function(){
        alert(s);
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status" checked>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so give it a value, `value="statusIsChecked"`

Comment: @Epodax Because... Aaaaand... That's why.

Comment: @Jay - It's my polite attempt of getting OP to remove the incorrect tag since I cannot do it myself without throwing it into the review queue and that's a "no no"

Comment: @andrew I want check status is checked or not. With your suggestion it always return `statusIsChecked`

Comment: @Hassaan it will return `statusIsChecked` **if** it is checked, otherwise it will return nothing

Comment: remove `checked` in checkbox field @Hassaan

Comment: @Epodax I know, dude. I was agreeing with you that there is absolutely no reason for it to be tagged as php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change from

```
var s = $('#status').val();
$("#status").change(function(){
    alert(s);
});
```

Into

```
$("#status").change(function(){
    if(this.checked == true)
    {
        s = 'on';
    }
    else
    {
        s = 'off';        
    }
    alert(s);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Just read the checked status in this way:

```
$("#status").change(function(){
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bh64jfsz/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/ph0neg95/)

You can use the following event to get the current value.

```
$('#status').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);


$('#status').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

    alert(this);
    alert(event);
    alert(state);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Can go for this:

```
$(function(){
            $("#status").change(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')) { alert('on');}
                else alert('off');
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :checked in jquery

```
$('#switch').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

correct answer is

```
$("input[name='courseFreePaid']").bootstrapSwitch('state');
```

This will return true or false